# Exporting for Compositing - Reference Video in Render

Tags: rendering, .exr

I'm trying to export a multi-layer EXR sequence. I remember encountering a similar problem about a year ago but I cannot remember what I did to fix it. Basically, the video reference I used for the camera tracking is also rendering with the 3D model. I turned the background off and don't know where else to look. I attached the a screenshot with some of the settings (don't consider the viewport).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Disabling the background collection makes only the scene objects disappear which are in this collection. I cannot see it clearly in your screenshot, but I guess what you see when rendering is the image that is in the *Background* material of the *World*.

And if I understand the question correctly you want the background to be transparent. To achieve this, go to the *Render Properties* > *Film* and enable *Transparent*.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for replying. Actually, transparency is on. The video I had initially imported into blender in the motion tracking page is showing in the final render. I can't find it anywhere to disable it

Comment: Do you have the video imported in the _Video Sequencer_?